# Saving the output from individual shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, r

I have a bash script that loops over iterations. How do i save the output from the individual scripts in the bash file according to the iteration?

```
#Working directory
cd /lustre/nobackup/WUR/ABGC/agyir001/
    
# Set the number of replicates
num_replicates=100

# Loop over the replicates
for i in $(seq 1 $num_replicates); do
# replicate number with leading zeros
rep_num=$(printf "%03d" $i)

output_file="accuracy_results_${rep_num}.txt"
  
#Run scenario 1,2 and 3 of male contributions

Rscript Scenario_1_male_contributions.R
Rscript Scenario_2_male_contributions.R
Rscript Scenario_3_male_contributions.R

#creating correlated qtl effects for 1000 selected qtls
Rscript Correlated_qtl_effects.R

#Selecting 1000 qtls, creating TBVS and phenotypes
Rscript Breeding_values_and_Phenotypes.R 7500

# prepare phenotypes and genotypes/markers
Rscript /lustre/nobackup/WUR/ABGC/agyir001/scripts/Markers_phenotypes_for_EBV.R
```

Comment: You do not need `rep_num=$(printf "%03d" $i)`. just use `seq -w 1 $num_replicates`

Comment: I used this because I wanted the data set to have 3 leading zeros as in some of the input files

Comment: You can use `-f` option of `sed` and set format to something like: `%04.0f` to print 4 digits with leading zeroes

Comment: Since `bash` version 3.1 without subshell: `printf -v rep_num "%03d" $i`

Comment: Will try this, thanks

Comment: You've got the solution yet, with $rep_num substitution, what is the question exactly ?

Comment: Yes, it has been solved now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the output of an individual command to a file named in the variable `output_file`, a regular redirection works:

```
Rscript Scenario_1_male_contributions.R > "$output_file"
```

or if you want both stdout and stderr

```
Rscript Scenario_1_male_contributions.R > "$output_file" 2>&1
```

If you want the output of many commands to the same file, you'd need to add the redirection to each, and to use `>>` for append mode instead of `>` which would truncate the file each time.

But, it might get a bit weary to add the redirections to each one individually, so you might want to use command grouping there:

```
{
Rscript Scenario_1_male_contributions.R
Rscript Scenario_2_male_contributions.R
Rscript Scenario_3_male_contributions.R
} > "$output_file"
```

Here, the regular redirection `>` is ok as the file is only opened once for the whole group. That is, assuming you don't want to save any data in the file from an earlier run of the script.

---

Or, in your loop to save the outputs of all `Rscript` invocations in the same file:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $num_replicates); do
    # replicate number with leading zeros
    rep_num=$(printf "%03d" $i)
    output_file="accuracy_results_${rep_num}.txt"
  
    {
        #Run scenario 1,2 and 3 of male contributions
        Rscript Scenario_1_male_contributions.R
        Rscript Scenario_2_male_contributions.R
        Rscript Scenario_3_male_contributions.R

        Rscript ...
    } > "$output_file"
done
```

Comment: Will this work for all iterations?

Comment: @Mabel, yes, the shell closes the output file when the command group finishes, and the next time `output_file` has a new name for the new redirection. Note that I wrote `>>` for appending redirection at first, but I suppose `>` would be more logical for the grouped commands if the output file is supposed to be new and there's no old data to save

Comment: I tried it and it seems to after every loop the output file is overwritten

Comment: The output file does not show at all